# Doctrine Symfony2 create schema issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, entity

I'm totally new to symfony2 and Doctrine.

i'm trying to create some entities which will made persistent data onto a db.
I've created my classes following Symfony's documentation.

I create the entities and run `php app/console doctrine:schema:create`

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare MyP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Alumno::__construct() in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\MyP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Alumno.php on line 306
PHP Stack trace:

[...]
```

This is my Entity Alumno:

```
<?php

namespace MyP\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Alumno
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyP\ProjectBundle\Entity\AlumnoRepository")
 */
class Alumno
{
[...]
    //Asociaciones base de datos

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Asignatura", inversedBy="alumnos")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Alumnos_asignaturas")
    *
    **/
    private $asignaturas;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->asignaturas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addAsignaturas(\MyP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Asignatura $asignaturas)
    {
        $this->asignaturas[] = $asignaturas;
    }

    public function getAsignaturas()
    {
        return $this->asignaturas;
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Posible_respuesta", inversedBy="alumnos")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Alumnos_posiblesRespuestas")
    *
    **/
    private $posibles_respuestas;

    public function __construct() //line 306
    {
        $this->posiblesRespuestas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addPosibles_respuestas(\MyP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Posible_respuesta $posibles_respuestas)
    {
        $this->posibles_respuestas[] = $posibles_respuestas;
    }

    public function getPosibles_respuestas()
    {
        return $this->posibles_respuestas;
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Solucion"), mappedBy="alumno")
    **/
    private $soluciones;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->soluciones = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addSoluciones(\MyP\ProjectBundle\Entity\Solucion $soluciones)
    {
        $this->soluciones[] = $soluciones;
    }
    public function getSoluciones()
    {
        return $this->soluciones;
    }
}
```

I suppose that i'm missing something.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Move `$this->soluciones = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();` inside the first `__construct()` you have and delete the second one. This is basic PHP. Have you followed the documentation or just copied/pasted the code from somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for that silly mistake. I didnt know how to use __construct() correctly.

Comment: We all do mistakes :)